# JsonPath ignore the Debug logs on output

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jsonparser, json-path-expression

I'm using `JsonPath` for my JSON parsing work in Java. Is there any ways to remove the `debug` logs upon running the code?

So basically, I am simply trying to run my parsing code in Maven:

```
String pageName = JsonPath.read(json, "$['pageInfo']['pageName']");
        System.out.println(pageName);
```

But when running the `jar` artifact file, it show the following as the first line:

`0 [main] DEBUG com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath  - Evaluating path: $['pageInfo']['pageName']`

How to ignore this line? This appears upon running each `JsonPath.read()` call.

**UPDATES**:

Initially I was getting some red-colored logs from `log4j` so added these dependencies. The red logs disappeared, but the above log (now black) appeared!

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I also add the `logBack` dependency. But still the code snippet can not be recognized:

[image]

Comment: If it's just a warning, can't you ignore it?

Comment: idk honestly! new to these

Comment: Look at the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was actually asked on 2017 on their official github page.

Looks like you need to use a logback as the log implementation

here is the code provided by andreasaronsson from the github issue

```
LoggerContext logContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger log = logContext.getLogger("com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath");
log.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

You need this in your dependencies

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For more closure about the issue you can find it [here](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/412)

Comment: What is ch? This snippet doesn't work. Something is missing.

Comment: `ch` is a package, Look at the github issue. you need that `Logback`

Comment: The issue doesn't help per se. Do I need to import something or add a dependency for this code to work?!

Comment: Yes you need to add `Logback` as a dependency

Comment: added the dependency. Still could not work. Please add all required steps.

Comment: That's all there is to it, You just add that code inside your main method.

Comment: If it still doesn't work are you sure you got the logback-classic jar? If not here is the direct maven link to it. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic

Comment: This is what I did. But it doesn't recognize the `ch.qos`, and `LoggerContext`.

Comment: If it still doesn't work are you sure you got the logback-classic jar? If not here is the direct maven link to it. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic

Comment: LoggerContext is from Log4J

Comment: Yes, added the maven dependency. So should I have both Log4J and logback? Look at my update.

Comment: Yes, You need both Log4J and Logback

Comment: Check updated answer, I have provided the xml for `dependencies`

Comment: It's funny. Now `LoggerContext` is resolved, but `ch cannot be resolved to a type` still there!

Comment: `ch` is not a class, It's a package. Can you replace `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` with `Logger` and see what are the options?

Comment: Also I think removing `<scope>test</scope>` will help I don't use maven.

Comment: Yay! It worked after removing `<scope>test</scope>`!

Comment: Updated answer to remove `<scope>test</scope>`

Answer (score 1):

What logging framework are you using? Just set the level of `com.jayway.jsonpath` logger to INFO or higher. Below are examples of doing that with XML config for [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) and [Log4j 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

*Logback*:

```
<configuration>
  …
  <logger name="com.jayway.jsonpath" level="INFO"/>
  <root level="DEBUG">          
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>  
</configuration>
```

*Log4j 2*:

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
  …
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.jayway.jsonpath" level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not using anything myself! But apparently jsonPath required `log4j`, so I added it to my dependencies. It was showing some red-colored messages, so I added some code to also ignore them. But this one appeared!

Comment: BTW, where to add these? Look at updates in my question.